# How to resolve System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'date' error?

Tags: sql, asp.net

I'm using a drop-down list in my asp.net web application.

I've bound the values using an SQL datasource.

But I'm getting and error on running it...

> "System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name
>   'date'."

Here is my SQL table:

```
create table dates1 (dates varchar(20))
insert into dates1 (dates) values 
   ('2018-12-23')
  , ('2018-12-24')
  , ('2018-12-25')
  , ('2018-12-26')

select * from dates1
```

I'm getting values in SQL. I've also cross verified the same column name being selected while bounding the data in drop down.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: your column name is dates not date  and seems you missed  a semicolon after the date values

Comment: No, even adding semicolon did not bring any solution. Also, the column dates have been selected while databounding

Comment: then the code you have posted  seems is not related to your question

Comment: Thanks, scaisEdge. I cross verified again. The SQL query what I posted was correct. I've selected the correct database, column while bounding the data. But still, I'm facing this issue

Comment: Your error references a column called `date` whereas your table contains a column called `dates` i.e. there is an additional `s`. If thats not the issue, please post your markup for both the `DropDownList` and `SqlDataSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do one thing drop this table create another table with everything same and column name as date varchar(20) its gonna work this time buddy